# Text in spoilers shows before being hidden

Tags: bug, spoilers

When there’s text in a spoiler, it loads and is completely visible (sometimes for quite a while on slow connections) before being hidden. It is kind of counterintuitive; could this be changed so that it isn’t visible while the page loads at any point?

> Demo of this minor problem

Comment: The problem is that HTML content has to be processed before CSS can be applied.  This is true even if the CSS is in-line in the page, but exacerbated if the CSS is in an external style-sheet that is separately loaded (even if just from cache).

Comment: This is certainly not a bug. At best, it would be a feature request (to find some other technical implementation).

Comment: It can also be influenced by connection speed, connection latency, and how your specific browser handles these.

Comment: I have a fast Internet connection and it doesn't show at all for me, but I've found this to be an issue on slow connections.

Comment: I can't reproduce this even when I use ["slow 3G"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32137673/6083675) throttling and reload the caches. On the other hand, I have problems with ignored tags not being immediately greyed out on the question lists, even over my normal fast connection.